# Get List of predefined size from RowMapper in Spring jdbcTemplate

Tags: java, spring, jdbctemplate

I have Following Code in which I have create list of objects according to batchSize
can any body suggest how to implement this ,I am thinking of checking rownum in rowmapper class equals batch size then problem is
how to return and create List from rowmapper implementation

```
public class TestAppDao {
public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

public JdbcTemplate getJdbcTemplate() {
    return jdbcTemplate ;
}

public void setJdbcTemplate(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
    this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
}

public List<Circle> getAllCircle(int batchSize){
    String sql = "select * from circle";
    return jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new Object[]{}, new CircleMapper());
}

private static final class CircleMapper implements RowMapper<Circle>{

    @Override
    public Circle mapRow(ResultSet resultSet, int rowNum) throws SQLException {

        Circle circle = new Circle();
        circle.setId(resultSet.getInt(1));
        circle.setName(resultSet.getString(2));
        return circle;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: I guess you could use the sql limit keyword to return only the number of circles you desire.

Comment: If the `select` returns fewer elements than your predefined size, is it an error?

Comment: Correct Abhinav ,previously I was using a count while iterating through resultSet.next() when count equals size, breaking loop and returning list of object

Answer (score 1):

I think you have basically 2 options:

- either to use `LIMIT` in `SQL` (your `DB` server however needs to provide support for it) (sample here: [Spring JdbcTemplate: how to limit selected rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9941488/spring-jdbctemplate-how-to-limit-selected-rows))
- or use `jdbc` `setMaxRows` - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#setMaxRows%28int%29

However second option doesn't guarantee that only so many results are returned from the `DB` server, as extra ones might be just cut by `JDBC` itself => it might be less performant (for oracle case, see: [How to limit number of rows returned from Oracle at the JDBC data source level?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320299/how-to-limit-number-of-rows-returned-from-oracle-at-the-jdbc-data-source-level))

I consider cutting it in your code as the worst option, as you need to iterate it yourself moreover you have no performance gain (always select all from DB).